Solving "array rotation leetcode #189" by recursive swap
I am working on the LeetCode problem #189 Rotate Array:

Given an integer array nums, rotate the array to the right by k steps,
where k is non-negative.

I tried to solve it by starting at element k then replacing every element next on the sequence. It works for some cases but for some others not all elements are reached and then I need to run the same code for k+1 and so on.
Code:
var rotate = function(nums, k) {
    let len = nums.length

    // start with element at index K
    let curr_index = k
    let curr_element = nums[curr_index]

    let target_index = -1

    // stop when a full cycle is completed
    while (target_index !== k) {
        target_index = (curr_index + k) % len
        const target_element = nums[target_index]

        // replace target with current element
        nums[target_index] = curr_element

        // set current to be equal to target
        curr_element = target_element
        curr_index = target_index
    }
};

it works for case [1,2,3,4,5,6,7], k=3 but does not work for case [1,2,3,4], k=2
is there any way of solving this problem with this "brute force" way of doing the rotations for real?

Yes, generally you need more than one loop (specifically, gcd(k, num.length) of them). Also be advised that your implementation is suboptimal: it moves every element twice. An optimal solution moves most of the elements only once.

I see now, it feels like an algebraic series, 0 -> 2k -> 3k -> 4k and if the value is larger than len we do mod len on each. and the series might be cyclic and does not touch all the numbers from 0...len, interesting!

Rotating brings to mind shifting, and javascript arrays has 4 relevant methods: shift, unshift, pop and push.
Let's go:


var rotate = function(nums, k) {
  k = k % nums.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < k; i++) {
    // this replaces in place
    // i.e: it changes nums array
    var x = nums.pop()
    nums.unshift(x)
  }
  // return nums
}


var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
rotate(arr, 12)
console.log("" + arr)



Here's a more efficient version (see comments). I will move each item to its destination (+k items ahead), then I will move the destination to its destination, and so on, until all nums.length items have been moved.
UPDATE: we must take care not to repeat ourselves into same place, for example when k = 2 and nums.length is even. That is why we always remember where we started (origin) and keep incrementing it by 1 if we complete a cycle. Again, all of this until nums.length items have been moved.


var rotate = function(nums, k) {
  var len = nums.length
  k = k % len
  if (k === 0) {
    return
  }

  function place(what, where) {
    var result = nums[where]
    nums[where] = what
    return result
  }

  var origin = 0
  var count = 0

  while (count < len) {
    var from = origin
    var to = (from + k) % len
    var temp = nums[origin]

    do {
      temp = place(temp, to)
      from = to
      to = (to + k) % len
      count++
    } while (from !== origin && count < len)
    origin++
  }
}

var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4]
rotate(arr, 2)
console.log("" + arr)




Good luck with the time complexity.

I've added a % there so it's O(n) now. One of the requirements was to modify array in-place.

unshift itself  is O(n ). Your solution is O(kn). There are at least two O(n) in-place approaches, and the OP is on the right track.

ok i didn't know that. i'll try to fix
